# How can I change HTML content by using node js

Tags: html, node.js

I want to change my HTML file (index.html) content bellow

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="greeting">Hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

to something else, by doing this in backend (Node js).
Here is nodejs code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res, ext) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

server.listen(8000);
```

Sorry for my English, if my words are not clear.

Comment: This is a bit too broad, do you have a node.js app that uses template engines or serves HTML on request?

Comment: Look at this repo https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: @Tran Linh See my answer.

Comment: Um, I find out away, using socket.io give me an answer similar to what I want

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to change the content of your

```
<div id="greeting">Hello world</div>
```

Would be to create an Index.js and

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


const theDiv = document.getElementById("greeting")

function NewContent(props){
    return(
        <div>
            New Content
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<NewContent/>, theDiv)
```

1. I have imported react and react dom
2. i have grabbed the greeting div and placed it inside of a "theDiv"
3. I have created a react Component called NewContent
4. I then tell react to render the newContent inside of theDiv

Comment: I just edit my question. If I run my HTML file on a server, how can I change its content at some particular event (such as click)?

Comment: @Ryan Tran wants to change the content by sending a request from his browser and such..I don't think he wants to use reactjs.

Comment: You have two major options -- one, put it into the front-end using javascript, and change it there. Ryan's suggestion to use React would let you do that.

Option two is to send a message to the server, then have the server generate a new page, and display that. You might consider reading up on nextjs for one way to 
 do that.

Comment: For some reasons, I want to do it in backend by using node js. Sorry, I'm so bad at this : (

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:-

Add a form to your `index.html` which sends a request when clicked:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="greeting">Hello world</div>
   <form action="/change-content" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Change content</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the node app you can listen to that:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res, ext) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/anotherFile.html');
});
```

so just make sure that you have another HTML file to serve when the button is clicked.

`anotherFile.html` can be anything you want

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>Node.js</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just one way to do it, typically you might want to use a better app structure and move your different HTML files into a folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pass data to my HTML file, what should I do??

Comment: If you want to pass dynamic data then you should use a template engine like EJS. It allows you to write javascript inside your template.